# ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE/DO NOTHING not working on FOREIGN TABLE

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

**ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE/DO NOTHING** feature is coming in PostgreSQL **9.5**.
Creating **Server** and **FOREIGN TABLE** is coming in PostgreSQL **9.2** version.

When I'm using  **ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE** for **FOREIGN table** it is not working,
but when i'm running same query on normal table it is working.Query is given below.

// **For normal table**

```
INSERT INTO app
 (app_id,app_name,app_date)
 SELECT
p.app_id,
p.app_name,
p.app_date  FROM app p
WHERE p.app_id=2422
ON CONFLICT (app_id) DO 
UPDATE SET app_date = excluded.app_date ;
```

**O/P : Query returned successfully: one row affected, 5 msec execution time.**

**// For foreign table concept**

**// *foreign_app* is foreign table and *app* is normal table**

```
INSERT INTO foreign_app
 (app_id,app_name,app_date)
 SELECT
p.app_id,
p.app_name,
p.app_date  FROM app p
WHERE p.app_id=2422
ON CONFLICT (app_id) DO 
UPDATE SET app_date = excluded.app_date ;
```

**O/P : ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification**

Can any one explain why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

There are no constraints on foreign tables, because PostgreSQL cannot enforce data integrity on the foreign server – that is done by constraints defined on the foreign server.

To achieve what you want to do, you'll have to stick with the “traditional” way of doing this (e.g. [this code sample](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE)).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in some cases there is a way to do it with **ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTION)**.  In my case, my first take was to try **ON CONFLICT...DO UPDATE**, but that doesn't work on foreign tables (as stated above; hence my finding this question).  My problem was very specific, in that I had a foreign table (*f_zips*) to be populated with the best zip code (postal code) information possible.  I also had a local table, *postcodes*, with very good data and another local table, *zips*, with lower-quality zip code information but much more of it.  For every record in *postcodes*, there is a corresponding record in *zips* but the postal codes may not match.  I wanted *f_zips* to hold the best data.

I solved this with a union, with a value of *ind = 0* as the indicator that a record came from the better data set.  A value of *ind = 1* indicates lesser-quality data.  Then I used *row_number()* over a partion to get the answer (where *get_valid_zip5()* is a local function to return either a five-digit zip code or a null value):

```
insert into f_zips (recnum, postcode)
select s2.recnum, s2.zip5 from (
    select s1.recnum, s1.zip5, s1.ind, row_number() 
            over (partition by recnum order by s1.ind) as rn from (
        select recnum, get_valid_zip5(postcode) as zip5, 0 as ind
            from postcodes
            where get_valid_zip5(postcode) is not null
        union
        select recnum, get_valid_zip5(zip9) as zip5, 1 as ind
            from zips
            where get_valid_zip5(zip9) is not null
        order by 1, 3) s1 
) s2 where s2.rn = 1
;
```

I haven't run any performance tests, but for me this runs in cron and doesn't directly affect the users.

Verified on more than 900,000 records (SQL formatting omitted for brevity) :

```
/* yes, the preferred data was entered when it existed in both tables */

select t1.recnum, t1.postcode, t2.zip9 from postcodes t1 join zips t2 on t1.recnum = t2.recnum where t1.postcode is not null and t2.zip9 is not null and t2.zip9 not in ('0') and length(t1.postcode)=5 and length(t2.zip9)=5 and t1.postcode <> t2.zip9 order by 1 limit 5;
  recnum  | postcode | zip9  
----------+----------+-------
 12022783 | 98409    | 98984
 12022965 | 98226    | 98225
 12023113 | 98023    | 98003

select * from f_zips where recnum in (12022783, 12022965, 12023113) order by 1;
  recnum  | postcode 
----------+----------
 12022783 |    98409
 12022965 |    98226
 12023113 |    98023

/* yes, entries came from the less-preferred dataset when they didn't exist in the better one */

select t1.recnum, t1.postcode, t2.zip9 from postcodes t1 right join zips  t2 on t1.recnum = t2.recnum where t1.postcode is null and t2.zip9 is not null and t2.zip9 not in ('0') and length(t2.zip9)= 5 order by 1 limit 3;
  recnum  | postcode | zip9  
----------+----------+-------
 12021451 |          | 98370
 12022341 |          | 98501
 12022695 |          | 98597

select * from f_zips where recnum in (12021451, 12022341, 12022695) order by 1;
  recnum  | postcode 
----------+----------
 12021451 |    98370
 12022341 |    98501
 12022695 |    98597

/* yes, entries came from the preferred dataset when the less-preferred one had invalid values */

select t1.recnum, t1.postcode, t2.zip9 from postcodes t1 left join zips t2 on t1.recnum = t2.recnum where t1.postcode is not null and t2.zip9 is null order by 1 limit 3;
  recnum  | postcode | zip9
----------+----------+------
 12393585 | 98118    |
 12393757 | 98101    |
 12393835 | 98101    |

select * from f_zips where recnum in (12393585, 12393757, 12393835) order by 1;
  recnum  | postcode 
----------+----------
 12393585 |    98118
 12393757 |    98101
 12393835 |    98101
```